# Use different css for input type text and checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm getting trouble when i try to change the width of my input checkbox.

all inputs are width:200px (text, button, checkbox). But i need a width:20px only for checkbox.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {width:20px}
```

but this is not completely browser compatible. All browsers will recognise if you add a class to your checkboxes, ie.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
```

then use:

```
.checkbox {width:20px}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=checkbox] { width: 20px; }
```

Comment: that is correct notation, but not works :) It will set width to 20px, but not visually. Try it, looks like added margins.

Comment: I paste it in my form.css file, but nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

You can set via CSS smaller size than default for checkbox but not larger. If you want to increase size of checkbox, you'll need jquery. Example [LINK](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/06/jquery-forms-plugins.html)

Comment: I will take a look, interesting custumized forms